Area & Perimeter of region $S$ containing points of the form $a+b\omega+c\omega^2$ where $a,b,c \in [0 , 1], \omega=-\frac 12+i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$
Question: Let $\omega=-\frac 12+i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$, and $S$ denotes the set of all the complex numbers in the Argand plane of the form $\boldsymbol{a+b\omega+c\omega^2}$, where $a,b,c \in [0 \, , \, 1]$. Find the Area and Perimeter of the region traced by $S$.

my attempt
$S$ contains all points of the form $(x , y)\equiv \left(a-\frac b2-\frac c2\quad, \quad \frac{(b-c)\sqrt3}{2}\right)$  where $a,b,c\in[0,1]$
Now, I general thing I cound remember is $\lvert a+b\omega+c\omega^2\rvert^2=\frac 12\left[(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\right]\\
\implies x^2+y^2=\frac 12\left[(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\right]$
so $x^2+y^2\ge 0$ if an upper bound of $\frac 12\left[(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\right]$ can be found then it might be inner portion of  circular region. Need help after it if I am going in right direction.

I won't give you a complete answer, but I will give you an outline for reasoning in an efficient way.

Suppose you have two vectors $\vec u$, $\vec v$ that are not parallel.  Then for $b, c \in [0,1]$, the set of all vector sums of the form $b \vec u + c \vec v$ forms a parallelogram in the Cartesian plane with vertices $(0,0)$, $\vec u$, $\vec v$, and $\vec u + \vec v$.  Can you see why?
Now consider the specific case where $\vec u = \omega$ and $\vec v = \omega^2$.  What does the region comprising points of the form $b \vec u + c \vec v$ look like, for $b, c \in [0,1]$?
Finally, consider what happens when you add a real number $a \in [0,1]$ to the quantity $b \vec u + c \vec v$.  What happens to this region as $a$ ranges from $0$ to $1$?
What is the shape that encloses all of the regions described in part (3) above?

